# Is it valid to average the credible intervals from many simulations to obtain an average credible interval?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, credible-interval

I am currently doing a Bayesian analysis where as output, I obtain a a point estimate. Each point estimate has an associated credible interval. Now, I am hoping to do the analysis 1000 times, then average these 1000 results.

I understand that it is valid to average over the 1000 point estimates. However, is it valid to average over the cutoff points for my credible interval? For example, assume that $p_1$ is the first point estimate with the credible interval of $\left(L_1,U_1\right)$

Then, we have:

$$
p_1,\ldots, p_{1000}
$$

as the set of point estimates and

$$
\left(L_1, U_1\right), \ldots, \left(L_{1000}, U_{1000}\right)
$$

the credible intervals.

Is it then fair to take the average over these 1000 intervals as:

$$
L^{avg} = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{i=1}^{1000}L_i
$$
and 
$$
U^{avg} = \frac{1}{1000}\sum_{i=1}^{1000}U_i
$$

so as to obtain the new credible interval of $\left(L^{avg}, U^{avg}\right)$ associated with $p^{avg} = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}p_i$?

Comment: Yes. Basically each of them is a posteriori sample,

Comment: Is there anything fundamentally wrong with averaging across intervals?

Comment: You don't have to think about "intervals". $L_i$, for example, is a posterior sample of some quantile, then $(L_1, \dots L_{1000})$ is a set of sample from the posterior of the quantile. And then the mean is a valid statistics that can be used to summarise this distribution

Comment: @niandra82 A different approach wouldn't be to combine all the posterior samples and find a universal $Lower$ and $Upper$ credible bounds?